Vega using a trigger to modify a row in a dataset
I'm trying to modify a value in a dataset (for a specific row and column) using a Vega trigger.  The reference includes a simple example for mark, not a dataset, however the page also states that it should be possible to modify a dataset.
Let my_data be a data set with columns a, b, c, d, e.  Column a has a unique value for each row.
Let s be a signal of the form [x, y], where x specifies the row to be modified (takes values in column a) and y is the value to set in column c.
I want to make c = s[1] when a = s[0].
Here's my attempt, not really sure what goes where so it is a bit of a wild guess (and it doesn't work).
...
    {
      "name": "my_data",
      "on": [
        {
          "trigger": "s",
          "modify": "s",
          "values": "{a: s[0], c: s[1]}"
        }
      ]
    },
...

The end goal is to highlight/unhighlight rows in a table view created in Vega (using text and rect marks) by having a column c maintain the selection status of the row.
